# Updating Datarow from List via for loop. Index was out of bounds

Tags: c#, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I have two string lists:

currentRow = contains the info that the row should have

currentCol = contains the names of the columns that data from currentRow should go in.

each List contains 25(0-24) items, and is ordered in the same way as the dataRow it should be written to.

I am filling the Lists here, from labels and textboxes on a form:

```
                List<string> currentRow = new List<string>();
                List<string> currentCol = new List<string>();

                foreach (var c in form11.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                    {
                        var str = c.ToString();
                        var str1 = str.Substring(35);
                        currentRow.Add(str1);
                    }
                    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                    {
                        var str = c.ToString();
                        var str1 = str.Substring(34);
                        currentCol.Add(str1);
                    }
                }
```

I then select the row in the dataTable that needs to be updated from the 3rd item in currentRow, which is a unique identifier.

```
var updateRow = arraysDt.Select("SERIAL =" + "'" + currentRow.ElementAtOrDefault(2) + "'");
```

Now i try to update the row from the items in the Lists here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.Count; i++)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(currentCol.ElementAtOrDefault(i).ToString() + "   " + currentRow.ElementAtOrDefault(i).ToString());
                    updateRow[0][currentCol.ElementAtOrDefault(i)] = currentRow.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
                }
```

As soon as it gets inside the for loop i throws a "index was out of bounds of the array" error.

As i said, currentCol contains column names and currentRow is the value. 
So when it get here i expect it to find the column name and then update it with the value.

```
updateRow[0][currentCol.ElementAtOrDefault(i)] = currentRow.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is i the count of rows or columns? 1)   i < currentRow.Count  2) currentCol.ElementAtOrDefault(i)  3) currentRow.ElementAtOrDefault(i)

Comment: @jdweng "i" is the count of how many items are in the lists. So the for loop should run the same amount of times as there is items in the list. which is 25 times. So where it says "currentCol.ElementAtOrDefault(i)" the "i" would be the column name, and currentRow.ElementAtOrDefault(i) would be the value it should be set to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the issue:

```
"SERIAL =" + "'" + currentRow.ElementAtOrDefault(2) + "'"
```

will give me this:

SERIAL=' XXXXX'

What i need is:

SERIAL='XXXXX'

so to fix it i did:

```
                string SMnum = currentRow.ElementAt(2).ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty);
                string query = string.Format("SERIAL='{0}'", SMnum.Replace(@"'", "''"));

                var updateRow = arraysDt.Select(query);
```

This removes any white space in the string that i am looking for.